How to electrically test Diamond FK0140 coil packs?
I have rust on my Subaru's coil on plug packs so thought to test resistance of the primary and secondary windings for all 6 coils to check for any inconsistencies.  These are the Diamond FK0140 with a 3-pin connector.
The car drives OK, feels like occasional minor misfires but no check engine codes. The spark plugs, injectors, O2's, intake, fuel pump etc. are healthy.
With the coils removed from the car I cannot get any resistance readings aside of open circuit with a multimeter between any combination the spark plug point, the stator or the 3 pins of the electrical connector. Any tips appreciated thanks.

